# value of duplicated array row changing original row

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, array-push

- ISSUE: value assignment to pushed row is affecting both rows.
- DESIRED OUTCOME: only assign new value to indicated row.

In google apps script, in the example below I push the last row into an array, so it's last two rows are duplicated. Then I want to change one value in the new row. Unfortunately, those two rows seem bound now, so any change to one affects both. Why and how do 'unbind' them?

```
function mre1 () {

  arr1 = [[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[3,4,5]]
  arr1.push(arr1[arr1.length-1]);
  arr1[arr1.length-1][1]=100;
  Logger.log(arr1);
  // ACTUAL [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [3.0, 100.0, 5.0], [3.0, 100.0, 5.0]]
  // DESIRED [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [3.0, 100.0, 5.0]]

}
```

Comment: Create a copy of the array that you're pushing: `arr1.push(arr1[arr1.length-1].slice());`

Comment: fair enough but why? any link to this other question or where this is explained somewhere?

Comment: `arr1[arr1.length-1]` holds a reference to an array in memory. When you push that reference to the end of the array, it still points to the same array in memory, it doesn't create a new array in memory. So when you modify it, it modifies the one array in memory. The `.slice()` create a new array in memory, and pushes the reference to that array into the end of your array

Comment: I guess that's all it could be. just hard to know how I'd know that. I'll get used to it though. maybe another 10 years coding and I'll figure it out...

Comment: Keep practicing and you'll get the hang of it. Objects (so things like arrays `[]`, object `{}` and functions) are _references_, whereas primitives (ie: booleans, numbers, strings, etc.) are stored as _values_.  There are many tutorials online that cover this particular topic ([here](https://wesbos.com/javascript/08-data-types/object-references-vs-values) is one example I found after a quick search)